# How to cancel/reset an UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

how can I cancel or reset an `UIGestureRecognizer`? The problem is, that if I set `waitForSomething` to `NO` during a gesture, the next event is `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`. But the first event should be `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

My Code:

```
- (void) panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if (waitForSomething) {
        // cancel or reset the recognizer!
        // because the next event should be UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and not UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
        return;
    }

    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            // important initialisation code
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I got it! :-)

Maybe someone else runs in this problem, here is the solution:

```
if (waitForSomething) {
    recognizer.enabled = NO;
    recognizer.enabled = YES;
    return;
}
```

The next event will be `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` followed by `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Comment: This is a great tip, and even recommended by Apple in a recent WWDC video

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
if waitForSomething {
    recognizer.isEnabled = false
    recognizer.isEnabled = true
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in more than one place:

in Swift

```
extension UIGestureRecognizer
{
    func cancel() {
        isEnabled = false
        isEnabled = true
    }
}
```